# Trying to getElementById from Walmart.com

Tags: javascript

I am really new to `JavaScript`, and Im basically trying to build a simple Script to get information from a site like Walmart.com. Im using firebug to test my little snippets. Im having a problem getting the price.

This is the my code:

```
var price = document.getElementById('clearfix camelPrice');
console.log(price);
```

I also tried `".camelPrice"` with out the period and I keep getting `null`.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: you may want to paste complete code. From this it looks like you're calling this line from your own site and hoping by way of black magic that it crawls walmart's dom.

Comment: `'clearfix camelPrice'` That looks like two class names, not an `id` value.

Comment: I think he's running the code in his browser console, which should work fine.

Comment: @twaddington - true, then document.getElementById('camelPrice') would work if this was an ID and not a class. However, he says he is trying to build a simple script. Console would not help in that case unless he is running his own tests ahead of time. EIther way he is not specific about his actions here.

Comment: See: [7.5.2 Element identifiers: the `id` and `class` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

Comment: Search [the source here](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Hometrends-Ashdown-3-Piece-Towel-Set/13025870) and you should be able to track down: `<div class="PricingInfo clearfix"><div><span class="clearfix camelPrice ">`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you're using the wrong method. `getElementById` does exactly what it says, it gets an element by its id. Looking on Walmart.com, 'camelPrice' is a CSS *class*.

We can still get elements by a class. What you want is `document.getElementsByClassName()`. Further, you can pass multiple arguments to `getElementsByClassName` like so:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('clearfix', 'camelPrice');
```

This grabs all elements that have both the `clearfix` and `camelPrice` classes set.

Comment: This is true, however it's worth noting that the getElementsByClassName method is relatively new and only available in the latest versions of a few browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/05/getelementsbycl.html

Comment: Looking at the compat tables, only IE has a version issue. Given that he's using a JS console, he's using Firefox or Chrome (compatible from the last several versions) or IE9, which is also compatible. :)

Comment: Yes, I agree with @twaddington; according to [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11), IE < 8 don't support it. It may not matter to some, but it should be noted for those who have to support IE7.

Comment: I would also note that in Firebug (FF10), if you do `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('clearfix', 'camelPrice'));` in the comment line, you do get a result. It happens to contain 127 elements it matched.

Comment: OP didn't necessarily mention what page he was using this code on; I'm just correcting the code he asked about, not doing all the work for him. :)

Comment: @yogi - `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.clearfix.camelPrice'));` in the Firebug command window [for this page](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Hometrends-Ashdown-3-Piece-Towel-Set/13025870) will give you: `<span class="clearfix camelPrice "><span class=""></span><span class="bigPriceText1">$22.</span><span class="smallPriceText1">97</span><span></span></span>` I think this is what you're looking for, right? Try: `var els = document.querySelectorAll('.clearfix.camelPrice .bigPriceText1, .clearfix.camelPrice .smallPriceText1');
console.log(els[0].innerHTML + els[1].innerHTML);`.

Comment: If we're not concerned about support, [`document.querySelectAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) would be a better suggestion, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the others have said about your selection looking like `id`s, here is how you can select by class name:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('classname');
```

Newer browsers allow you to make jQuery-like selections from native JavaScript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#id .classname');
```

http://caniuse.com/queryselector

Comment: Might also help: [MDN's `document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to provide a class selector to `getElementById` instead of an ID selector. This is what an ID looks like:

```
<div id="some-id">...</div>
```

This is what a class looks like:

```
<div class="some-class">...</div>
```

The difference is that only one element should ever have a specific ID on a page, where many elements might have the same class.

Comment: See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611267/trying-to-getelementbyid-from-walmart-com#comment-12194814) above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are running your JavaScript in Walmart's site, which is not impossible, but maybe you should specify it, for instance if the Walmart site is in an iframe you will not be able to use getElementById() from your site.

On the other hand if you are running some sort of local Live Editor/Console, then maybe it is possible.

For the script you show above, you have an error on the ID since an id can only be one word, and you are missing to select what type of attribute you want from the element:

For example, `<input>`:

```
var price = document.getElementById('id').value
```

or for other tags like `<div>`:

```
var price = document.getElementById('id').innerHTML
```

Comment: RE: *I am not sure how you are running JavaScript in Walmart's site, which is **not possible*** - It is, using [Firebug's command line](http://getfirebug.com/commandline) for instance. Open [this page](http://getfirebug.com/commandline), open the console tab (in Firebug or Chrome Console), make sure the command line is open, and try: `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.smallScreen'));`.

Comment: Might also be of interest: [Firebug Tutorial – Using Commandline API in Firebug](http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/15/firebug-tutorial-commandline-api).

Comment: To be fair, he said it was __not impossible__.

Comment: "Not Impossible" haha, I also said "On the other hand if you are running some sort of local Live Editor/Console, then maybe it is possible." Any way, just trying to clarify.